# Referencing ActionScript file

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a process set up to create action script files. They hold functions that are called upon by my flash project. How can i reference these files so that the project knows the functions are there.

with asp.net i would simply reference the .js file. Is it the same process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of importing files to be used by Flash is pretty straightforward:

At the top of each external file there will be a `package` declaration, it basically represents it's path **from the .fla file**.

For example:

```
package com.site.objects
```

The above represents an ActionScript file within a folder *objects*, within *site*, within *com* whose parent folder also contains the .fla file.

When you're importing external files, you always start from the directory containing the .fla. This is always necessary with the exception of importing external files that are in the **same directory** as the file you're trying to access the class from.

The import statement for the above example will look like this:

```
import com.site.objects.MyClass;
```

Once you've done this, you'll be able to:

1. Create instances of the imported class.
2. Access static properties and methods defined within the class.
3. Extend the class to create a new class which will inherit it's properties.

etc